# Plotting multiple functions with pyplot, passing functions into functions, & reusing code

Tags: python, function, math, parameters, arguments

I want to plot multiple arbitrary math functions while reusing code for getting coordinates and plotting them.

Comment: Also, I forgot that the x/y coord list needs to be cleared for each plot: `x_coords.clear()` & `y_coords.clear()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the function itself and not the call to it.

```
getCoords(myFunction, 42)
getCoords(anotherFunction, 69)
```

You could restructure to something like this. Having a dedicated function to produce the coordinates and a dedicated function to draw them:

```
def myFunction(x):
    return (3*(x**2)) + (6*x) + 9


def get_coords(fun, num):
    for n in range(num):
        yield n, fun(n)


def draw_graph(coordinates):
    for x, y in coordinates:
        plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")
    plt.show()


draw_graph(get_coords(myFunction, 45))
```

Comment: I see that now. Python always surprises me with its flexibility. And thank you for introducing ```yield```